# get the number from string by regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.0.99"
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.9.99"
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.19.99"
```

I want get the number(0.99, 9.99, 19.99). I tried to do like this:

```
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.0.99".scan(/\d/).join
=> "099"
```

Anyone can help me get the correct result. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, [regexp](http://rubular.com/r/4XLiZNerOg) for numbers like `0.00` or `00.00`:

```
\d{1,2}.{2,}
```

- `\d` Any digit
- `\d{1,2}`    Between 1 and 2 of digit
- `.` a dot
- `\d{2,}`     2 or more of digit

Example:

```
>> "com.abcd.efghi.pay.19.99"[/\d{1,2}.{2,}/, 0]
=> "19.99"
>> "com.abcd.efghi.pay.9.99"[/\d{1,2}.{2,}/, 0]
=> "9.99"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.0.99".split(/\D+/, 2).last # => "0.99"
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.9.99".split(/\D+/, 2).last # => "9.99"
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.19.99".split(/\D+/, 2).last # => "19.99"
```

or

```
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.0.99".sub(/\D+/, "") # => "0.99"
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.9.99".sub(/\D+/, "") # => "9.99"
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.19.99".sub(/\D+/, "") # => "19.99"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

which looks for an integer followed by an optional fractional part.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
"com.abcd.efghi.pay.0.99".scan(/(\d+[.]\d+)/).flatten.first
# => "0.99"
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
str = "com.abcd.efghi.pay.0.99"

str.split(".").last(2).join(".") # => "0.99"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex in `scan`:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use end of the line anchor.

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so many ways. Here are a couple more:

```
str = "com.abcd.efghi.pay.9.99"

str[str.index(/\d/)..-1] #=> "9.99"
str.sub(/.*?(?=\d)/,'')  #=> "9.99"
```